# No Virtualization Technology on my Virtual PC; other ways to install Virtual Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, iphone, virtual-machine

I need some other solution to install my Virtual Windows XP in my computer (running in Windows 7) that will support USB (my iPhone, I'm trying to install WinPwn that is only compatible in Windows XP and below). I recently installed VirtualBox thinking it would solve my problem installing Windows XP but my virtual XP in VirtualBox didn't detect my iPhone. It can only detect my USB portable drives.

Another that I did is installing Windows Virtual PC but my CPU isn't ready for virtualization.

Is there any other solution that you can suggest to solve my problems? Basically my reason to install virtual Windows XP is I need to install WinPwn for my iPhone that is only compatible with Windows XP and below.

Comment: As I said before, there are other tools other than WinPwn to achieve what you're looking for. Try that route before installing an entire OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other solution I can think of is to set up a dual boot scenario with Windows 7 and XP. The XP installation should have access to all hardware at all levels.

There are other questions on SU regarding dual booting if you need further help.

Comment: Yeah, I think I would go for dual boot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/).  It doesn't require hardware virtualization and it just might recognize you iPhone.